# How to resize 28x28 pixels image to 20x20 pixels?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mnist

I want pixels in the size 20x20 but when I imported it from MNIST it is in 28x28 pixels. How can I convert this to 20x20 pixels in Matlab?

Comment: Is it larger because of some padding that you can crop off? You can resize it, but you're really going to lose a lot of information if you do that. The interpolation is just going to destroy your images.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the Matlab documentation, you can use the following [`imresize`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html#zmw57dd0e86548) syntax for it:

```
B = imresize(A, [20 20])
```

Comment: This is for single image, i want to do for MNIST dataset

Comment: Just loop over all the images in the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible things you can do:

1) crop the image: You will lose information of the image, use this if you are sure that the data you are deleting is noise and is not necessary for the future.

```
I = imcrop(Image,[Coordenates Rectangle]);
```

2) Resize: There are differents methods used to downsampling or upsampling your image based on the local or general information.

```
J = imresize(Image, factor or [new dimensions], 'method');
```

The methods available are:

1. 'nearest'
2. 'bilinear'
3. 'bicubic' (values could be in a diferent range from the original data)